# Divide and conquer algorithm to find position of max element

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to find the index of the max element in an array using a divide and conquer algorithm. Currently, the output is correctly outputting the maximum value of my array, but I cannot figure out how to pass the position of that maximum element.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;  


int maxElement(int a[], int l, int r) {
   if(r - l == 1) {
        cout << "R - L == 1 " <<  "Array value: " << a[l] << " Pos: " << l << endl;
        return a[l];
   }
   int m = (l + r) / 2;
   int u = maxElement(a, l, m);
   int v = maxElement(a, m, r);
   return u > v ? u : v;    
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main() { 
    int Arr[] = {1, 4, 9, 3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 9, 3, 7};
    int arrSize = sizeof(Arr)/sizeof(Arr[0]); 

    cout << maxElement(Arr, 0, arrSize) << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If you know an index, you can get the value in O(1), but if you only know the value, then it takes O(n) (maximum) to iterate through the array and find the index. Have `maxElement` return an index instead of a value.

Comment: Instead of returning `a[l]` you can return `l`. And `u` and `v` becomes the indexes of max element. You can compare  and return `a[u]>a[v]?u:v`

Comment: This is a nice academic excersize, certainly. Unfortunately, it does not really do  anything useful or extraordinary. You simply can't get around the fundamental requirement to compare every element in your array. In this case, this is a requirement imposed by some fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe, and the shown code accomplishes that task. But the same will be done, also, by a simple, garden-variety `for` loop. Nor recursion required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a `std::pair` which contains both the *array value* & *position*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;  


std::pair<int, int> maxElement(int a[], int l, int r) {
   if(r - l == 1) {
        cout << "R - L == 1 " <<  "Array value: " << a[l] << " Pos: " << l << endl;
        return {a[l], l};
   }
   int m = (l + r) / 2;
   auto up = maxElement(a, l, m);
   auto vp = maxElement(a, m, r);
   return up.first > vp.first ? up : vp;    
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main() { 
    int Arr[] = {1, 4, 9, 3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 9, 3, 7};
    int arrSize = sizeof(Arr)/sizeof(Arr[0]); 
    auto result = maxElement(Arr, 0, arrSize);
    cout << result.first << ", l = " << result.second << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: question is what if maximum has duplicates? If first maximum should be returned then your fix fails (fix is simple): https://godbolt.org/z/MbY9EM9M4

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the Index of Max Element without using
Pair 
I hope this will help you

```
int DAC_Max_Postion(int arr[], int index, int l)
{
    int max;
    if(index >= l - 2)
    {
        if(arr[index] > arr[index + 1])
            return index;
        else
            return index + 1;
    }
    max = DAC_Max(arr, index + 1, l);
    if(arr[index] > arr[max])
        return index;
    else
        return max;
}
```